# Context manipulating

Tags: watson-conversation

I have a list of context passed to the conversation from my application. Context looks like:
  "stock_availability": [
      {
         "item": "Mango",
         "info": "available",
         "quantity": "20"
      },
      {
        "item": "Apple",
         "info": "notavailable",
         "quantity": "30",
      }

Here I'm checking condition as if $stock_availability.item=="Apple" and if $stock_availability.info=="notavailable", then show the user other available items within the same response/ may be next response. How to do this? How do i store the notavailable item and show the user only available items?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the logic you want to implement?

Answer (score 0):

In the response you could have something like the following:

```
We have the following available: <? $store.?[info=="available"].![item] ?>
```

This should return `[Mango]`. [The expression language Watson Conversation is using is documented here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html). At the top of that page is a reference to SpEL. It provides more background and I found it useful to dig into that.